# How do I disable devices to conserve power?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, battery-life, powertop

I run ArchLinux on a Lenovo G series and downloaded powertop and it says that USB bluetooth and "USB device: Lenovo EasyCamera" are drawing a lot of power. While it advised I implement these rule:

```
Autosuspend for USB device Lenovo EasyCamera [Vimicro corp.]    echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power/control';
Autosuspend for USB device Bluetooth USB Host Controller [Atheros Communications]   echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/power/control';
```

I'd prefer to just turn it off completely, as I use neither feature. I used `rfkill` on bluetooth, but it's still showing up in Powertop. I read that you just need to unload the kernel module using

```
# rmmod <module-name>
```

I've blacklisted `bluetooth` and `btusb` and ran `rmmod`, but the device is still showing up. Do I need to reset for the changes for the changes to take place, or am I just unloading the wrong modules? If the latter is the case, how do I know which module to unload? I've run udevadm, I still don't know which module to blacklist.